# KDE Plasma night color wont turn off

Tags: kde

I activated night mode a while ago on ubuntu 20.04, but rotating shifts now have me wanting it off.

Problem is, the apply button is permanently greyed out. So any changes I make, I browse away from the tab in settings, it turns off but then turns back on within 30 seconds.
Even when I click default in the tab, the settings don't stay

Is there a configuration file I can edit somewhere to force these changes?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1333797/edit) your question to mention which version of Ubuntu you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=411584

I've been having issues with night color the whole time I have been using Kubuntu 20.04 - I have been fully unable to change Night Color in the normal settings window since I very first set it up when I installed the OS. This is a documented bug that only occurs on some systems - KDE has repeatedly stated it is resolved as of Plasma 5.18 or 5.19 despite users still continuously complaining that it is still around.

Today though was the first time I also experienced the inability to manually turn it off using the taskbar control button when I signed in this morning.

You can edit night color settings in /home/yourusernamehere/.config/kwinrc. You can then apply changes in that file, including forcing it to be active or inactive, by restarting kwin using the terminal command:

> kwin_x11 --replace & disown